# Is a MITM attack possible in this scenario?

Tags: networking, apt, security, key-authentication

OS is Debian. Imagine I have my own apt repo set up inside a private network.

This repo is set up to provide a single package to other servers on this network.

I can easily create a signing key for my repo, but this scenario got me thinking.

As far as I understand, the key is needed so that whatever system downloads the package knows the package wasn't tampered with.

Could a MITM attack happen between a server and my repo? If so, how would that happen? Seems impossible since both the repo and the server are inside a private network, but I would like to understand this better.

Comment: try asking  at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Yes a MITM attack can happen but unless you explicitly bypass the signature checks (https://askubuntu.com/questions/74345/how-do-i-bypass-ignore-the-gpg-signature-checks-of-apt) or the the initial connection when the public key is imported is compromised, the attack wil be inneffective.

Comment: Thank you! How would a MITM attack happen on a private network?

Answer (score 0):

For an intruder to carry out a MITM attack inside your private network, they have to:

- gain access to that private network
- compromise one of your machines or install their own malicious server
- do a ARP Spoofing attack to associate their MAC address with the IP address of the legitimate network node hosting the repo, or a DNS spoofing to associate their IP address to the hostname of the repo node.

At this point they can successfully intercept and manipulate traffic intended for that repo node. They won't even need to carry out a a MITM; they can set up a fake repo node to direct all client requests towards it. It is worth noting that if a client has already downloaded the public key of the repo, then it will receive a warning that the pubkey has changed (as said by @symcbean in a comment).

However, what is important to understand here is that you now have an intruder inside your network, which from their privileged position can carry out any kind of attack: sniff traffic, inject viruses, steal and change data, perform a DoS, replace legitimate applications with malicious ones, etc. So you should not focus on a specific kind of attack (MITM in this case) but ensure that your private network is protected against external and internal attacks.